# creating simple button to use the size of column from bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My idea is to create a simple green button. No text, no border, just a green shape, which would inherit the size of `col-md-12` from bootstrap. I have seen there are many similar questions, however I have a problem with basic understanding so I would appreciate if you would help me understand it.

```
<body>
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <button class="button" type="button" style="border:none; display:inline-block; color:green;"></button>
   </div>
</body>
```

So, this is what I did. I have a body and I have a `col-md-12` class. This is ok I guess. Then I decided to create a button. I have a button tag, `class=button`, `type=button` and I have a style > simple green color and inline-block to display this button over `col-md-12`. However! Nothing happens. May I ask why?

**I don't want to put any sizes for purpose, I want just to fit whole col-md-12**. May I ask what I don't understand correctly? Thank you.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you utilizing?

Comment: bootstrap 3, bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Bootstrap's grid classes only work within rows and those rows have to be within a container. Also you need to give your button a width of 100% if you want it to stretch.

Comment: j08591, so I need to create div container, div row and div column?

Comment: See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Yes, I did inserted container class and row class, but it doesn't work. On the other side this works perfectly: <body> <div class="col-md-12"> <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button> </div> </body>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by j08691, you have to embed your columns inside rows for it to work properly:

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="button" type="button" style="border:none; display:inline-block; color:green;"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

But this wont be enough, because by default your button will not take the whole space, so you need to add a `width: 100%;` property on it:

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="button" type="button" style="width: 100%; border:none; display:inline-block; color:green;"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/w1njoLL0/

Comment: I copy pasted your second code, but still nothing. it frustrates me, because this works: <body>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button"></button>
    </div>
</body>

Comment: The second code is working for me. I added a demo that is indeed working.

Comment: O.K. i typed hello in <button></button> and i get same solution as you in demo. However, I would really like to get just a green button with no text. If i delete the text, nothing happens. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, you just need to set an height on the button: https://jsfiddle.net/w1njoLL0/4/ By the way, in order to set the background color, the property is `background-color`, while `color` is for the text color.

Comment: AntonieB, I like your code, it is better, however I am thinking now how to avoid 40px in height. Is there a way to express this with % like for width? Thank you.

Comment: It is pretty hard to do, you have to set an explicit height on the parent (so the direct parent `div`) to be able to set a % width on there.

Comment: Thank you very much for letting me know, however i think form-control in first answer is working in this way. But thank you for all the help

Answer (score 3):

Just add a class 'form-control' to button tag.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1njoLL0/3/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-success form-control" type="button">Hello</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `w-100` to the button's class, e.g.:

```
    <div class="mt-5 row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-3">
        <button id="continue-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg w-100">
          Continue
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```